# MobileFirst 7.1 - Access disabled for older version, but users are still able to access

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Two months back we released latest version of application and disabled all older version using MobileFirst console. But when looking at WRKLGHT.CLIENT_INSTANCES table we have observed that even after 2 months users are still able to access older version. Is this a bug with MobileFirst? 
Or am I missing any thing was I suppose to do anything else to completely disable older version.

Comment: 1. mention your exact build number of 7.1 server. 2. mention if you have modified the behavior of the application in case of remote disable in any shape or way (like a cancel button that does a different behavior, etc. 3. Are you sure the application is disable? If you use yourself a disabled version of your app, is it disable? Are you able to reproduce this?

Comment: 1) Server version: 7.1.0.00.20160801-2314. 2) nothing was changed for disable feature. 3) I am not able to reproduce it but I see these entries in WRKLGHT.CLIENT_INSTANCES which is confusing part.

Comment: But those could be old instances and not new instances.

Comment: IT has current dates. Like some users connected today as well with older version.

Comment: Are you sure you maybe have some 7.1 build releases that are not disabled?

Comment: We have release 4 versions so far. 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0. Our 1.2 and 2.0 ate in active mode so any entries with that does not bother me. But I still see entries with 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: This question may be too complex for stack overflow. I suggestion to remove it and open a PMR instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this theory based on the mentioned in the comments, where a remotely-disabled device still makes new records in the database - but I do not see any new such records being made (you too also could not reproduce this).

This question really goes outside what can be handled in Stack Overflow and so I suggest to open a PMR and provide server logs, and to attempt to recreate this, as without a recreation there is not much then can be done...